# Auth laravel 5.5 con una tabla diferente

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando hacer una autenticación de usuarios con una tabla diferente a 'users' que es la que tiene por defecto Laravel, mis campos de tabla se llaman diferente en este caso "correo" y "contrasena"

No logro hacer la autenticación ya que no me reconoce el campo "contrasena" solo logro que haga el login cuando el campo se llama "password"

Hay alguna manera de cambiar esto para que me reconozca el campo "contrasena"? 
ya intente implementando el método **getAuthPassword** pero no me funciono.

Tengo el Siguiente código en el LoginController

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{


    // funcion que solo permite dejar pasar al usuario a la rutas si hace sesion
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

        $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => 'showLoginForm']);
    }


    // retorna a vista login
    public function showLoginForm(){

        return view('login');
    }


    // funcion para inciar sesion
    public function login(){

        $datos  = $this->validate(request(), [
            $this->username() => 'email|required|string',
            $this->getAuthPassword() => 'required|string'
        ]);


        // valida si lo datos son correctos crea la sesion
        if (Auth::attempt($datos)) {

            return redirect('ventas');
        }

        // si son incorrectos devuelve un mensaje
        return back()
            ->withErrors([$this->username() =>  trans('auth.failed')])
            ->withInput(request([$this->username()]));

            //return $this->getAuthPassword();
    }


    // funcion para cerrar sesion
    public function logout(){


        // cierra sesion y devuelve al login 
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/');
    }


    public function getAuthPassword () {

        return "contrasena";

    }

    public function username(){


        return "correo";
    }

}
```

El siguiente código en el modelo de User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombres', 'correo', 'contrasena',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `getAuthPassword()` debería añadirlo al modelo `User` , básicamente con este método podemos `setear` cuál será el campo de nuestra tabla que funcionará como `password` a verificar para el `Auth::attemp`

Esto se puede ver en el namespace `namespace Illuminate\Auth;` ahí está la clase `DatabaseUserProvider` el cuál posee un método `validateCredentials` que accede a este método en el modelo para saber si se ha `seteado` con otro valor.

El `if` del `attemp` se modificaría

```
$datos  = $this->validate(request(), [
     $this->username() => 'email|required|string',
     $this->getAuthPassword() => 'required|string'
]);
    // valida si lo datos son correctos crea la sesion
if (Auth::attempt(['correo'=> $datos['correo'] , 'password' => $datos['contrasena'] ] ))
```

y su modelo `User` debería tener el siguiente código *(por lo menos)*

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'usuarios';

    protected $fillable = [
         'nombres', 'correo', 'contrasena',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'contrasena',
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->contrasena;
    }

}
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIASSSS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Me funciono a la perfección había estado buscando mucho y no lograba encontrar una solución

TE AGRADEZCO INFINITAMENTE  !

Comment: @CarolinaVelasquez Qué bueno que haya servido . Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la mejor solucion, por si a alguien le sirve. este fue mi código de mi control.

```
public function login()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(request(['Uso_Login', 'Usu_Password']), [
            'Uso_Login' => 'required|email',
            'Usu_Password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        $dates = [
            'Uso_Login'=>$validator->validated()['Uso_Login'],
            'password' => ($validator->validated()['Usu_Password'])
        ];

        if (!$token = Auth::attempt($dates)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Contraseña o usuario no validos'], 401);
        }
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
```